# Does data transfer between lightsail and S3 cost any? [Same Region]

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

I've been wondering if data transfer between lightsail and S3 is free.

For example, data transfer **OUT** from S3 to my lightsail instance, on the **SAME** region let's say ap-northeast-1

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Lightsail FAQ: What does data transfer cost?](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/):

> Your plan includes a free data transfer allowance. Both data transfer in and data transfer out of your instance count toward your data transfer allowance.
>
> If you exceed your data transfer allowance, you will only get charged for data transfer OUT from a Lightsail instance to the Internet or to AWS resources using the public IP address of the instance.

It appears that accesses out to AWS Services over the public IP Address (like S3) will count towards your data transfer allowance, and once this has been consumed, you will be charged data transfer fees.

Comment: hi, thanks. :) There’s one point I can’t understand well, for EC2 instance on the same region, I could reduce the costs to ZERO by configuring VPC, adding VPC endpoint policy as well as s3 bucket policy. So I was trying to configure VPC peering in lightsail.     However, I found this in lightsail document: Some AWS Resources , such S3, don’t require VPC peering to be enabled. I’m just not sure whether these words mean that I don’t have to consider VPC stuff. :) Sorry this may take longer time to digest.

Comment: I think you're looking at [Set up Amazon VPC peering to work with AWS resources outside of Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/lightsail-how-to-set-up-vpc-peering-with-aws-resources), is that correct? For context, when they're talking about VPC peering, they're talking about it in relation to AWS Resources like the AWS Relational Database Service that are designed to run in a VPC. S3 on the other hand was designed to run across the open internet, but in an an AWS VPC, can be configured to access from inside the VPC. Lightsail appears to lack this.

Comment: hi thanks for offering the help. I see, maybe I could just ask their staff then :)

Comment: and yes, I was reading this doc you just mentioned above, so I’m pretty confused, to be honest. :(

Comment: sorry I don’t answer questions a lot, although I really want to upvote your answer, I just can’t :(

Comment: This answer mention lightsail pricing but what about S3?